# Creating a file using make fails but works with Eclispe

Tags: eclipse, makefile

Im trying to run a makefile using bash that is normally ran with Eclispe on a mac. The file is:

```
#Project variables for prebuild.h
PROJECT_NAME := myproject
VARIANT := RELEASE

#Create prebuild.h file
CREATE_FILE := $(shell echo "/* Generated file. Do not edit. *//" > ../prebuild.h)
CREATE_FILE := $(shell echo "#define PROJECT_NAME \""$(PROJECT_NAME)"\"" >> ../prebuild.h)
CREATE_FILE := $(shell echo "#define VARIANT \""$(VARIANT)"\"" >> ../prebuild.h)
CREATE_FILE := $(shell echo "#define $(VARIANT) \""$(VARIANT)"\"" >> ../prebuild.h)
```

the error Im getting is the following:

```
bash-3.2$ make
../makefile.defs:7: *** unterminated call to function `shell': missing `)'.  Stop.
```

It works from Eclispe on a mac, why not from bash?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a bug or two in make (at least with my version -- 3.81), dealing with # signs...

Interestingly:

```
$(info #this works)
VAR := $(info #this doesnt)
VAR := $(info \#this does)

$(shell echo #this works > tmp.txt)
VAR := $(shell echo #this doesnt >> tmp.txt)
```

The best solution is to write this as a target and recipe as so:

```
../prebuild.h:
    @echo "/* Generated file. Do not edit. *//" > $@
    @echo "#define PROJECT_NAME \""$(PROJECT_NAME)"\"" >> $@
    @echo "#define VARIANT \""$(VARIANT)"\"" >> $@
    @echo "#define $(VARIANT) \""$(VARIANT)"\"" >> $@
```

Otherwise either upgrade to a later version of make, or have make call a shell script that does the work for you.